# Backslash in ticks in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

## Test one

The test is to render a backslash in code block:
Transcript:

```
....\\....\(KKK\)
```

Rendering

```
\\\(KKK\)
```

## Test two

The test is to render a backslash in `backquotes`
Transcript

```
`\\\`..
`\(KKK\)`
```

Rendering:
`\\\`
`\(KKK\)`

Now performing the same in the comments (see below) and the rendering is different.

ps. In transcript `.` means `<space>`

Comment: Test one:

    \\    \(KKKK\)

Comment: Test two: `\\\`  `\(KKK\)`

Comment: Test two part two only: `\(KKK\)`

Comment: Test two part one only: `\\\`

Comment: Added additional comment to the meta.so.com 

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11388/backslash-escaped-with-backticks-rendered-incorrectly-in-comments/59179#59179

Comment: For formatting of backticks and backslashes in posts, see the [Formatting Sand-Box](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3150/5764). Also, see [this comment](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208/formatting-sand-box#comment8717_208) for comment-related formatting of the symbols.

Answer (score 4):

That's part of the Markdown syntax, personally I'm not thrilled about it either (specially within backticks), but that's how [it's documented](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash).

Incidentally, I was just writing a comment and it took me ages to figure out how is one supposed to enter a `coded` line-break.

Here `\\` works.

```
Here `\\` works
```

But on a comment I had to type

```
On a comment `\\ `, because `\\` doesn't work!
```

inconsistent and not practical at all!

Comment: On a comment `\\ `, because `\\` doesn't work!

Comment: Well, the documentation also talks about backslash escapes for `{`, but this isn't in effect in inline code in comments.

Answer (score 4):

So is it different in comments and answers?  If I do

```
`\( ... \)`
```

then it works as I expect: `\( .. \)`.

---

**Edit:** Okay!  So that's an inconsistency between the two and I'd rate that a bug.

Comment: So let's try in a comment: `\( .. \)`.

Comment: See? Now it works, even in old comments!

Comment: Single backslash inside tick marks: `\`

Comment: Double backslash: `\\`

Comment: Triple backslash: `\\\`

Comment: Quadruple backslash: `\\\\`

Comment: 5 backslashes: `\\\\\`

Comment: What about empty backticks? ``

Comment: What if I add spaces? No backslash (backtick-space-space-backtick): `  `

Comment: Do spaces collapse? (1 space, "1", 2 spaces, "2", 3 spaces, "3", 4 spaces)
 ` 1  2   3    `

Comment: Why are they not working? `abc`

Comment: 5 spaces in the middle: `before     after`

Comment: Any way to get multiple spaces? What about backtick-"before"-2 spaces-backslash-2 spaces-"after"-backtick? `before  \  after`

Comment: What about alternating letters and backticks? Backtick on both ends: `a`b`c`d`e`f`g`h`

Comment: What if I use non-breaking spaces? "a", 3 NBSPs, "b": `a   b`

Comment: "a", space, NBSP, space, "b": `a   b`

Comment: @SolomonUcko Could you add your own answer to test on, please?  I just got 14 notifications from your comments!

Comment: Sorry. I'll do that next time. I do wonder if there's any way to have multiple spaces in a row in the output, though.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem in a comment to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/bad-spacing-of-math-letters-within-italic-text/3496#3496) answer to a question of mine, and it's a real pain. Is there any hope that this bug gets fixed in the near future? (I know that answers are not really a place to ask questions, but my aim is just to give the original post here some more emphasis.)

---

This now [got implemented as follows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981): Backslash escaping in inline code in comments is disabled, except for a *backtick* `` ` `` within *single* backticks `` `...` ``.
For the two examples: ``` ``\\\`` ``` gives `\\\`, and `` `\(KKK\)` `` gives `\(KKK\)` (note that there are no line breaks and hence no code blocks in comments). For details [have a look here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code/864#864).