# How do I mark inline code?

Tags: support, faq, markdown, code, code-example

How do I mark my inline code in questions and answers, and how can I mark code in comments?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The simplest way is to surround the inline code by backticks `` ` ``: To get the output `\section`, just type `` `\section` ``. If you don't like typing backticks, you can also highlight the inline code and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (or click the "code" button, with "{ }" on it), but this doesn't work in comments. In **questions and answers**, there are only two (quite rare) cases where things might go wrong (see below for backslash escaping of backticks in comments):

1. You need a backtick in the inline code. Then you can *either* use double backticks ``` `` ``` *or*  `<code>...</code>`  to mark your code. For example, both

   - ``` ``\catcode`@=11`` ``` and
   - `` <code>\catcode`@=11</code> ``

   give `` \catcode`@=11 ``. Another example: ``` `` "` `` ``` gives `` "` `` (note the spaces!).
2. You want spaces in the beginning and/or the end of the inline code, or you need multiple spaces within. Then you have to use `<code>...</code>`:

   ```
   <code>&nbsp;a &nbsp; test&nbsp;</code>
   ```

   gives  `a   test` , which has 3 spaces between "a" and "test".

Thus, `<code>...</code>` is an alternative for backticks, but it behaves differently: You can use HTML entities such as `&nbsp;` inside. For example, `<code>&nbsp;</code>` gives  , whereas `` `&nbsp;` `` gives `&nbsp;`.

As a rule of thumb, use `<code>...</code>` only as a last resort. And then be aware that you can run into trouble if you try to use `<` inside: `<code>a<b</code>` gives `a`! The way out: `<code>a&lt;b</code>` gives `a<b`. Moreover, `<code>a < b</code>` gives `a < b`.

---

Until 20 February 2011, markdown in **comments** [was quite a hassle](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/168/1235). Now the rules are [almost the same as for questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981). These are the differences:

1. `<code>...</code>` to mark inline code doesn't work in comments.
2. If you need a backtick in inline code in a comment, you can (and must) escape it (doesn't work in questions/answers!): `` `\catcode\`@=11` `` gives `` \catcode`@=11 ``.
3. #2 means that `` `\\` `` will *not* give `\\` because the second backslash is interpreted as an escape for the subsequent backtick. This can be solved by using double backticks ``` `` ``` if the inline code ends with a backslash: ``` ``\\`` ``` gives `\\`.
4. It is not possible to have spaces in the beginning and/or the end of inline code in comments.

One more important recent change: Inline code in comments can now be followed by a letter. For example, `` `\vspace`s `` now renders as `\vspace`s.

Comment: @Hendrik: Can you tell me how to backtick-quote something like "` (German opening quote). No combinations so far work. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10867/quotation-with-double-quote-and-o-results-in-o/10869#10869) where I had this issue.

Comment: Found it. HTML came to the rescue: `<code>"&#96;</code>`

Comment: @Martin: Easy, use double backticks, but _with spaces_: `\`\` "\` \`\``.